# how to sql distinct value inside a column that have multiple string delimeter by ','

Tags: mysql, distinct, group-concat, distinct-values

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y2OvD.png)

hello everyone , i'm trying to generate new table using mysql that have difference value (which means eliminating duplicate) in the same column that have so much of string.

I already try group_concat(distinct column_name asc column_name separator ',') but it doesn't give the result i want ,

Important: I want different values inside a column

The picture no 1 is before sql and the number 2 is after group_concat sql ,it's still having duplicate there.

Thank you

Comment: Do **NOT** store data this way.  Such structures present multiple problems. **Normalize** your data.

Comment: i'm not storing data like that , that table in the picture is the result from more than one group_concat() command

Comment: Then *may be* you need to reconsider an order of operations, so aggregate concatenation comes after all filtering.

Comment: thanks for your suggestion , appreciate that :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it but you should take PM77-1s advise and you should normalize your data.

That said... you can do it the following way with a temporary-table:

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE temp (val CHAR(255));
SET @S1 = CONCAT("INSERT INTO temp (val) VALUES ('",REPLACE((SELECT GROUP_CONCAT( DISTINCT hashtag_name) AS data FROM hashes), ",", "'),('"),"');");
PREPARE stmt1 FROM @s1;
EXECUTE stmt1;
SELECT group_concat(DISTINCT(val)) as hashtag_name FROM temp;
```

I've made a working Fiddle.
(because SQLFiddle is not workable these days I used rextester.com)
http://rextester.com/HMUC89223

Result:

```
    hashtag_name
1   tido,makan,ittify,general,ittified,travel,lifestyle,minum,air,keyboard,lepak,gg,nice
```

Comment: thank you a lot!!!!!!!! , this is exactly what i want ,so happy , btw , i'm not storing data like that , that table in the picture is the result from more than one group_concat() command , thank you againnn!!!

Comment: @bathulahmahir Happy to help, and welcome to Stack Overflow. If this answer or any other one solved your issue, please mark it as accepted with the checkmark at the left.